# Problems with a step in this proof. [generalized quaterion group]

Tags: group-theory

Here is the theorem whose proof I am trying to work through:

> A finite p-group G having a unique subgroup of order p is either cyclic or generalized quaternion.

And here is the part of the proof I am stuck in:

> The proof is by induction on $n$, where $|G|=p^n$; of course theorem is true when $n=0$.
>
> Assume first that $p$ is odd. If $n>0$, then $G$ has a subgroup $H$ of index $p$, by Exercise 4.2(*p-groups contain normal groups of every order*), which must be cyclic, by induction.

Here is my problem, why must $H$ be cyclic. It follows from induction that $H$ is either cyclic or a generalized quaternion, but why must it follow that $H$ is cyclic. Does having a generalized quaternion subgroup imply that there must be two disjoint subgroups of order $p$?

Edit: $p$ is prime

Comment: the variable $p$ is usually used for prime numbers. Is there perhaps an assumption of primality that you've missed?

Comment: Oh I am sorry yes $p$ is prime

Comment: And does that answer your question?

Comment: Well no, being that $|H|=p^{n-1}$ doesn't imply that $H$ is cyclic. For example if $G=Z_4\times Z_2$ then we could have $H\cong Z_2\times Z_2 $, but in this case $G$ wouldn't have a unique subgroup of order $p$. I concerned with the fact that the author doesn't assume $H$ could be a generalized quaternion instead of simply cyclic(which also follows from induction).

Comment: Sorry. I thought it said $H$ was of order $p$, but I see now it is of index $p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that you assume that your prime $p$ is **odd**. The generalized Quaternion group has order $2^n$ for some $n$.

Comment: Thank you sir you are a god send.